# How can I make an Angular.forEach loop synchronous?

Tags: angularjs

I am making a request to URLs in my forEach loop. I want the calls to be made synchronously...

```
angular.forEach(param, function(value) {
    FactoryWithURLCallingFunction.URLCallingFunction(param1, value, param3).success(function(data){
        console.log("Url returns: " + data);
        });
    });
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Why do you want them _synchronously_? You may be better off nesting the `promises` ?

Comment: Use the `$q.all` method https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: @christiandev - because I require the first request to the url to complete and return before I can start the next one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not make synchronous AJAX requests (although, it's possible), it's a sure way to making irresponsive UI. Instead, use proper [promises capabilities](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all):

```
$q.all(param.map(function(value) {
    return FactoryWithURLCallingFunction.URLCallingFunction(param1, value, param3).then(function (response) {
        console.log('Url returns:', response.data);
        return response.data;
    });
})).then(function(data) {
    console.log('All loaded:', data);
});
```